# Trying to generate PDF using TCPDF but getting an fatal error?

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf

```
   Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

    (mypath)tcpdf/tcpdf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

while executing i'm getting the fatal error , Please provide any solution to solve this issue and generate an pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
require_once('yourpath\tcpdf\tcpdf.php');
```

and write full path or relative path manually.